# How to search Contacts (address book) for company records - Mountain Lion

Tags: objective-c, osx-mountain-lion, addressbook

How could you search through the contacts (aka address book) in Mountain Lion, using Objective-C, to find all company records (i.e. `kABShowAsCompany`) with the same company name as the current person record? For example, if I have a person record with company "Acme Corp" I want to find all company records with name "Acme Corp".

I need to return an `NSArray` of records with flag `kABShowAsCompany` and `kABOrganizationProperty` equal to `kABOrganizationProperty` of the current record.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I removed the other problem you mentioned at the end. Like you said, that is a separate question you could ask once you solve this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString* acmeCorpCompanyName = @"Acme Corp" ;

ABAddressBook* addressBook = [ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook] ;
ABSearchElement* isACompany = [ABPerson searchElementForProperty:kABPersonFlags  label:nil  key:nil  value:@(kABShowAsCompany)  comparison:kABEqual ] ;
ABSearchElement* nameIsAcmeCorp = [ABPerson searchElementForProperty:kABOrganizationProperty  label:nil  key:nil  value:acmeCorpCompanyName  comparison:kABEqualCaseInsensitive ] ;
ABSearchElement* isACompanyNamedAcmeCorp = [ABSearchElement searchElementForConjunction:kABSearchAnd  children:@[isACompany, nameIsAcmeCorp] ] ;
NSArray* foundCompanies = [addressBook recordsMatchingSearchElement:isACompanyNamedAcmeCorp] ;
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you. I was almost there but didn't know how to handle the person flags in the search. Now I do! Thanks again.